# SAP Link User-Defined Field to normal SAPB1 table field

Tags: foreign-keys, sapb1, user-defined-fields

In SAP we can add link from User-Defined field to User Defined Table? Is it possible to link UDF to normal SAP Table, for example, to Business Partner Table?
I need kind of foreign key from my UDF to SAP table (added with DI API or manually)

Answer (score 0):

Business One version 9.2 added a new validation option of "Linked to Entities" for UDFs. However, as of PL4 it has the restriction that a link to a standard system table can only be made from a UDF on another standard system table (using the 'Link to System Object' option). Furthermore the standard tables you can link to is a fairly small list:

- GL Accounts
- Business Partners
- Stock Items
- Payments
- Journal Entries
- Warehouses
- Most marketing documents

(This list taken from PL04)

It doesn't appear to be possible to link a UDF on a UDT to a standard table.